# How to remove verbosity from log4j

Tags: grails, log4j

My log4j log file looks like this.

```
 2018-01-12 09:21:33,082 [http-nio-8080-exec-39] INFO  diversotron.PropotronService  - ...connected to Selenium Standlone webdriver
 2018-01-12 09:21:33,727 [http-nio-8080-exec-39] INFO  diversotron.PropotronService  - ...attempting to read propotron.ini file.
 2018-01-12 09:21:33,744 [http-nio-8080-exec-39] INFO  diversotron.PropotronService  - ...GDS server name from the propotron.ini file is gdsfareqa2
 2018-01-12 09:21:34,750 [http-nio-8080-exec-39] INFO  diversotron.PropotronService  - ...attempting connection to Propotron.
```

I'd like to get rid of the date, the "[http-nio-8080-exec-39]" text the log category INFO and the service name. Is that possible?

What would the pattern look like to do that?

```
 def pattern = new PatternLayout("%-5p [%t]: %m%n")
```

Any help vastly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This might help.  I use slf4j, and have a logback.groovy file in the grails-app/config directory.  Looks like you can configure it in the Config.groovy file

http://snipplr.com/view/63391/grails-log4j-for-different-environments--an-example/

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

def pattern = new PatternLayout( "%m%n" )